# Docker service start failed - Debian 11

Tags: python, linux, docker, server, debian

I have Debian 11 with installed docker. After successful installation, docker service could not started.

`sudo systemctl start docker`  output:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`sudo systemctl status docker.service` output:

```
soft@p633466:~$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-05 19:00:05 MSK; 41s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 9932 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 9932 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`journalctl -xe` output:

```
soft@p633466:~$ journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
Oct 05 18:07:49 p633466.vps systemd[8931]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-metacopy\x2dcheck139345502-merged.mount: Succeeded.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Oct 05 18:07:54 p633466.vps sudo[9109]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 05 18:08:09 p633466.vps systemd[8931]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-check\x2doverlayfs\x2dsupport2562965269-merged.mount: Succeeded.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Oct 05 18:08:16 p633466.vps systemd[8931]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-metacopy\x2dcheck750605051-merged.mount: Succeeded.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Oct 05 18:58:55 p633466.vps su[9860]: (to root) soft on pts/0
Oct 05 18:58:55 p633466.vps su[9860]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by soft(uid=1000)
Oct 05 18:59:47 p633466.vps su[9860]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Oct 05 18:59:56 p633466.vps sudo[9871]:     soft : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/soft ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start docker
Oct 05 18:59:56 p633466.vps sudo[9871]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by soft(uid=1000)
Oct 05 18:59:57 p633466.vps systemd[8931]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-metacopy\x2dcheck941122558-merged.mount: Succeeded.
```

Linux kernel version:

```
soft@p633466:~$ uname -a
Linux p633466.vps 4.19.0 #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 12:58:54 MSK 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Debian version:

```
soft@p633466:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
```

I tried reinstall docker and etc. Also rebooted server multiple times, didnt help

Answer (score 1):

Run from the root cli:

`/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`

Post the log if the error is not clear

Comment: INFO[2023-10-06T20:05:58.503280545+03:00] Starting up                                  
failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd.

I got this error

Comment: Try to change the ExecStart from fd:// to unix://:

See:
https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-load-listeners-no-sockets-found-via-socket-activation-make-sure-the-service-was-started-by-systemd/62505